# I cannot use enter to insert code from suggestion vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know why my VSCode keep break the line when I want to get the snippet from the suggestions through enter.

[image: Problem]

Here is my setting for the suggestion.

[image]
Please help me

Comment: are you inside a snippet when this happens?

Comment: Possibly related: [VsCode Accept Suggestion on enter Not Working :(](/q/74965778/11107541)